# A script to update multiple Database rows

Tags: php

I'm not quite sure how to go about this, I have echoed out information in a while loop in PHP "id, name, description, date, albumid, path", but I have it so the author can edit anything they want, then click the save button and everything updates.

I need a script which will update everything row by row, but I don't know a way I can do this as I know that if you update with a Mysql UPDATE you need to create a query everytime, So how would I store all of the information, from every unique field and update them at the same time?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do it with one UPDATE? Why not just loop through each row and do an UPDATE on each one?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET field = CASE id
                   WHEN 1 THEN 'foo'
                   WHEN 2 THEN 'bar'
                   ...
                   ELSE 'baz'
               END
```

This query will set the `foo` value to the `field` into the row with `id = 1`, etc